# Parsing Html ios using hpple help required

Tags: html, ios, parsing, hpple

I'm currently trying to parse the following content from a HTML website:

```
< div class="box"><br>
< script>...< /script><br>
"mytext"<br>
< br><br>
"mytext"<br>
< br><br>
"mytext"<br>
< script>...< /script><br>
< div class="cube">< /div><br>
< /div><br>
```

How can I get all of **mytext** by searchWithXPathQuery?

Comment: if you are just using xpath there is function called `.text()` to extract the tags from the node. But the question is not very clear so i am assuming that you have this HTML in some node so just do `node.text()`

Comment: I tried this [xpath searchWithXPathQuery:@"//div[@class='box']//text()"]; but still not works